# Angularjs select2 set options selected

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I want to build select list (select2) options when user clicks on html button.

My HTML:

```html
<select id="mySel2" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="item.selected"
            ng-model="item.tag">
      {{item.tag}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Angular js  function code on button click:

```
var fruits=angular.module("myApp",[]);
fruits.controller('ctrlTags',  function($scope){

  /* I HAVE SET DEFAULT VALUE TO SELECT LIST*/
  /* IT WORKING PERFECT WITH SHOWING SELECTED VALUES*/
    var tagsData = [
      {id:1,tag:'Apple'},
      {id:2,tag:'Banana'},
      {id:3,tag:'Cherry'},
      {id:4,tag:'Cantelope'},
      {id:5,tag:'Grapefruit'},
      {id:6,tag:'Grapes',selected:true},
      {id:7,tag:'Lemon'},
      {id:8,tag:'Lime'},
      {id:9,tag:'Melon',selected:true},
      {id:10,tag:'Orange'},
      {id:11,tag:'Strawberry'},
      {id:11,tag:'Watermelon'}
    ];  

     $scope.items = tagsData;

     /*NOW ON BUTTON CLICK GETKEY() FUNCTION WILL BE CALLED*/
     /* AND I WANT TO RENDER/REFRESH SELECT LIST WITH NEW DATA */
     $scope.getKey=function(data){   
         var newData = [
          {id:4,tag:'car'},
          {id:5,tag:'bat',selected:true},
          {id:6,tag:'cat',selected:true},
          {id:7,tag:'Lemon'},
          {id:8,tag:'Lime'},

        ];
    $scope.items=newData;

    };
});
```

ISSUE:ON BUTTON CLICK IT IS UPDATING SELECT LIST VALUES BUT NOT SHOWING DEFAULT SELECTED VALUES

PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO REFRESH SELECTED VALUE AS WELL.

Comment: `ng-model` shouldn't be placed on `option` element, do place it on `select`, also that should have different name

Comment: code is still working correct. but having only issue  of setting selected values from ng-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add model into select section ng-model="selected".
You can add for example first index 
 in controller $scope.selected = tagsData[0]

Comment: It is working on initial load. But not working when button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Use `select2` (form-widgets.js)

```
$('[name="NAME"]').select2({placeholder: ''}).val(VAL).change();
```